# Backspace key not working in vim

Tags: vim, backspace

I am using vim under Terminal.app and just a few days ago the backspace key stopped working. Whenever I am in insert mode, the backspace key does nothing.

However, when I am in normal mode, the backspace key moves the cursor back a character. In visual mode, the backspace key deletes selected text.

> [My .vimrc](https://gist.github.com/d16b33ca4003eaf46bc1).

Is there any way to get the backspace key working in insert mode again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you didn't change anything, it's odd that it was working and now isn't. That aside, I normally add this to get the most out of the backspace key with Vim:

```
set bs=indent,eol,start     " Backspace over everything in insert mode
```