# backspace not working, even after attempted fix

Tags: vim, backspace

I tried following the instructions in [Backspace key not working in vim](https://superuser.com/questions/202848/backspace-key-not-working-in-vim) , but I still have the same problem: BACKSPACE inserts a `^?`

That is to say: inserting `set bs=indent,eol,start` in my `~/.vimrc` did not solve the problem.

I am sure that I am loading the correct source file (I did a test of another setting, and the change propagated).

I am using: `Vi IMproved 7.2` on Ubuntu with Gnome. In the terminal application, backspace works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim seems to be confused about what your terminal sends as the erase character. As this varies between `^?` (<kbd>Ctrl+?</kbd>, or `DEL` for "delete") and `^H` (<kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> or `BS` for "backspace"), Vim depends on someone telling it what to expect.

That shouldn't happen unless

- you're changing related settings in your `vimrc`,
- you're changing the value of the `TERM` environment variable,
- your terminal information database is messed up, or
- you're suffering from a gremlin infestation.

For troubleshooting, try to run the command `stty erase ^?` before starting Vim, and see if this fixes it. Enter the `^?` not separately as `^` and `?`, but by first pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, then your <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. If your shell is well-behaved, this should produce a literal representation of whatever your terminal sends when you hit that key.

Comment: Thanks, `stty erase ^?` worked for me. I added it to my `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gnome-terminal then there should be a setting to have backspace emulate ^H.  There are similar settings in other terminal emulators; it's the first place I would go since no one else has mentioned it.

[image: Accessing profile in gnome-terminal]

[image: Setting backspace behavior]

Answer (score 1):

Found this question while searching for something mildly related, and thought I'd post a pedantic (but possibly helpful) follow-up.

Most modern versions of stty(1) (including the version shipped with GNU Coreutils) interpret the two-character sequences `^` `?` and `^` `h` as the control sequence ASCII <kbd>DEL</kbd> and ASCII <kbd>BS</kbd> (respectively). Or more generally, two-character sequences starting with `^` as their equivalent ASCII control character.

So the two following commands are equivalent:

```
stty erase '^?'
stty erase ^VDEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .bashrc ( or .profile )
stty erase ^H
That is the character "^" followed by the character "H"
--or--
If that does not work, to get "^H" type control-V followed by control-H

See vim help
:help gui-pty-erase