# backspace not working properly inside vim comEmu

Tags: vim, conemu

When I start vim from inside conEmu, then backspace is not working properly. I know its not a conEmu issue. It's a vim problem with console. I tried all things  like

`stty erase ^H, stty erase '^?', set bs=2` etc.,

I have also tried the advice at
[Backspace key not working in vim](https://superuser.com/questions/202848/backspace-key-not-working-in-vim)

but none of this worked!

Any advice for solving this.

Comment: Which OS? Does it work if you use something else than conEmu? What does control-h do if you try it?

Comment: Microsoft Windows7.

If I press Ctrl+H then it delete a character.

And I am getting the same issue from inside cmd.exe. But I use conEmu that why I have specifically mentioned it.

Comment: I suppose, this may be a bug in ConEmu ANSI sequences processor.

Comment: comEmu is perfect It is not having this bug. 
As this problem happens in cmd.exe also.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the backspace problem I had with ConEmu in the terminal vim (backspace registered as delete) by adding the following lines to my `.vimrc` file (or `_vimrc`):

`inoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>
nnoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>`

See https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/641.